# creating new column while iterating through pandas dataset (multiple conditions)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a new column applying multiple conditions on a column having datatype as float.

```
Sample data:
ID  CO
0        12.0
1        11.0
2         8.0
3         6.5
4         5.5
5         5.7
6         5.8
7         6.5
8         6.8

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['CO'] in arange(0,1.54):
        row.loc['CO_1'] = 'GOOD'
    elif row['CO'] in arange(1.54,1.70):
        row.loc['CO_1'] = 'MOD'
```

Above did not work, so i tried to write a function separately:

```
def aqi_CO(row):
    val_1=0
    for x in row:
        if x in arange(0,0.054):
            val_1 = 'GOOD'
        elif x in arange(0.054,0.070):
            val_1 = 'MODERATE'
        elif x in arange(0.070,0.085):
            val_1 = 'UNHEALTHY_SG'
        elif x in arange(0.085,0.105):
            val_1 = 'UNHEALTHY'
        elif x in arange(0.105,0.200):
            val_1 = 'VERY_UNHEALTHY'
        elif x in arange(0.200,3):
            val_1 = 'HAZARDOUS'
        return val_1
```

and called it by apply:

```
df['aqi_CO'] = df.apply(lambda x: aqi_CO(df['CO']), axis=1)
```

This did not work as-well. Im confused now, Can someone help me how should I add new column iterating through the dataframe row by row and checking 3,4 conditions to create new column.

Comment: USING `pd.cut` and lable

Comment: "Didn't work" is unclear: did it cause an error (please show the traceback), did it cause unexpected output (please show expected and unexpected output), or did it do nothing at all?

Comment: `if row['CO'] in arange(0,1.54):` probably doesn't do what you want. If you want `if 0 < row['CO'] < 1.54`, then use that. `np.arange(0, 1.54)` just creates `array([ 0.,  1.])` and the if statement will look if `row['CO']` is one of the elements in that array (0. or 1.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `pd.cut`

```
pd.cut(df.CO,bins=[0,2,4,6,8,9,100],labels=["GOOD","MODERATE","UNHEALTHY_SG","UNHEALTHY","VERY_UNHEALTHY","HAZARDOUS"])

Out[866]: 
0       HAZARDOUS
1       HAZARDOUS
2       UNHEALTHY
3       UNHEALTHY
4    UNHEALTHY_SG
5    UNHEALTHY_SG
6    UNHEALTHY_SG
7       UNHEALTHY
8       UNHEALTHY
Name: CO, dtype: category

df['new']=pd.cut(df.CO,bins=[0,2,4,6,8,9,100],labels=["GOOD","MODERATE","UNHEALTHY_SG","UNHEALTHY","VERY_UNHEALTHY","HAZARDOUS"])
df
Out[868]: 
   ID    CO           new
0   0  12.0     HAZARDOUS
1   1  11.0     HAZARDOUS
2   2   8.0     UNHEALTHY
3   3   6.5     UNHEALTHY
4   4   5.5  UNHEALTHY_SG
5   5   5.7  UNHEALTHY_SG
6   6   5.8  UNHEALTHY_SG
7   7   6.5     UNHEALTHY
8   8   6.8     UNHEALTHY
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first snippet of code:
`arange(0,1.54)` returns `array([ 0.,  1.])` and nothing from sample data lies in  it. However, if you want to
check then, you can increase the range and step size a well.
Something like `arange(0, 7, 0.1)` then, for the next step in your for loop, you use `.loc` with `index` with `dataframe` instead of `row`, `df.loc[index,'CO_1'] = 'GOOD'` instead of `row.loc['CO_1'] = 'GOOD'` :

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['CO'] in arange(0, 7, 0.1):
        df.loc[index,'CO_1'] = 'GOOD'
    elif row['CO'] in arange(1.54,1.70):
        df.loc[index,'CO_1'] = 'MOD'
```

Result:

```
     CO  CO_1
ID            
0   12.0   NaN
1   11.0   NaN
2    8.0   NaN
3    6.5  GOOD
4    5.5  GOOD
5    5.7  GOOD
6    5.8   NaN
7    6.5  GOOD
8    6.8   NaN
```

Similarly, for the second snippet of the code, may be using lambda and apply to only column:

```
df['aqi_CO'] = df['CO'].apply(lambda x: aqi_CO(x))
```

Now, since only column value is passed it can checked without iteration in function (*Note: the function range for first case is changed so, that output can be seen*):

```
def aqi_CO(x):
    val_1=0

    if x in arange(0,7, 0.1):
        val_1 = 'GOOD'
    elif x in arange(0.054,0.070):
        val_1 = 'MODERATE'
    elif x in arange(0.070,0.085):
        val_1 = 'UNHEALTHY_SG'
    elif x in arange(0.085,0.105):
        val_1 = 'UNHEALTHY'
    elif x in arange(0.105,0.200):
        val_1 = 'VERY_UNHEALTHY'
    elif x in arange(0.200,3):
        val_1 = 'HAZARDOUS'
    return val_1
```

Result:

```
     CO aqi_CO
ID             
0   12.0      0
1   11.0      0
2    8.0      0
3    6.5   GOOD
4    5.5   GOOD
5    5.7   GOOD
6    5.8      0
7    6.5   GOOD
8    6.8      0
```